# How to uninstall a firefox plugin?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, java

I was trying to play minecraft in the browser, and I got asked to install a plugin called "IcedTea-Web Plugin (using IcedTea-Web 1.2 (1.2-2ubuntu1))" (something related to Java 6), which I can see now in Tools > Addons > Plugins. There was another plugin to install (for Java 7), I didn't know if I had to select one, so I just clicked Install or Accept.

Now the game or java app only shows a black screen, so I thought I should uninstall the plugin and try installing the other one. But there doesn't seem to be a way to uninstall plugins through the firefox GUI.

Any ideas?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question so apologies if I have, but you should be able to do this from the add-ons menu. When you go to that there should be a link for plug-ins that lets you disable any of them. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @GarryCairns I don't know, because I need the install menu to pop up again so I can install the other plugin, so I thought I needed to uninstall, instead of disable (disable plugin and reload page didn't make the install menu to pop up).

Comment: Okay I'm with you now [this note](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons#w_how-to-uninstall-plugins) suggests plug-ins come with their own uninstall methods. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comment on the question, mozilla provide [some instructions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Troubleshooting+plugins#w_manually-uninstalling-a-plugin) for manually uninstalling.

> ## Manually uninstalling a plugin
>
> If you can't use an uninstaller program to remove a plugin, you can
>   remove it manually:
>
> 1. In the [Location bar](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Location%20bar%20autocomplete), type **about:config** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    - The about:config *"This might void your warranty!"* warning page may appear. Click <kbd>I'll be careful, I promise!</kbd>, to continue
>        to the about:config page.
> 2. Search for the preference: `plugin.expose_full_path`.
> 3. Double-click on the `plugin.expose_full_path` preference in the list to change the value to `true`.
> 4. Enter **about:plugins** into the Location bar to display the About Plugins page.
> 5. Each entry in the About Plugins page will have "File name:" followed by a path. Use Windows Explorer to navigateNavigate to the
>      folder shown for the plugin you want to remove.
> 6. Rename the file to something other than its normal name - e.g. *npswf32* becomes *Xnpswf32*
> 7. Double-click on the `plugin.expose_full_path` preference in the list on the about:config page to change the value back to `false` to
>      avoid exposing the plugin path to websites.
>
> The plugin will be removed.

<sub>The above [Mozilla.org community-contributed content is made available](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/legal.html#site) under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which permits properly-attributed derivative works distributed under the same license. CC-BY-SA is also the license that [covers content here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/faq#editing). Its formatting is changed very slightly to accommodate the StackExchange format. The page from which the above block-quote was taken lists [Bo102010](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/26), [cor-el](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/287), [Verdi](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/160087), and [scoobidiver](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/209080) as contributing authors.</sub>

Comment: When I do that, the plugin will still be there with the path set to the renamed file, how can that be?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

1. go to Firefox> tools> Add-ons> Plugins
2. click on "more" under each plugin you want to remove.
3. Where it says "File"; highlight the file's name e.g. xxxxxxxxxxx.plugin
4. Then copy the name by "holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in Windows or holding <kbd>down command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in Mac.
5. Open the finder (in Mac) or search (in Win) and paste the address in there.
6. It will find the file.
7. Delete it. In mac ask for your permission (confirmation) by typing your personal login password.
8. when you removed the file, return to the plugins page in Firefox (main page)
9. You will see that you are able to remove it from the list know.

This solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **tools menu**, or click on the "open menu" button, present on the rightside top corner of your browser.
2. click on **Add ons**.
3. to your left side of the screen you will see many options, and the last one will be "**Recent Updates**", click on it.
4. you will see the addons , just click on the remove button.

## note:

If you didn't get the menu "Recent Updates", follow this for step 3, click on the icon near the search box, the icon has an image of screwdriver, in that you will see "Recent Updates".